# Vuejs route loading based on user type

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am returning user type in all my components but i need to add validation of it in my routes, not sure how to.

## Code

This is my `route.js` file where the routes i need users to be authenticated are defined in `meta`

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import store from './store';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    routes: [
        // ADMIN ROUTES
        {
            path: '/dashboard',
            name: 'dashboard',
            component: Dashboard,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                layout: 'admin'
            }
        },
    ]
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
      if (!store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
        next({
          name: 'login'
        })
      } else {
        next()
      }
    } else {
      next()
    }
  })

router.afterEach((to, from) => {
    Vue.nextTick(() => {
        document.title = to.pageTitle || 'CC';
    });
});

export default router;
```

As you can see I have `requiresAuth: true,` which only allows authenticated user to access this route, I also need to add another value which says `if user type == admin` that way not all logged in users can access to such route but only admins.

This is my logged user info which is accessible in all components and is included `type` value

[image: one]

### Question

How can I add user type to routes meta?

> **Note**
>
> my type value can be one of this 3 conditions
>
> 1. **admin** (admins role)
> 2. **customer** (any other user role)
> 3. **undefined** (user with no role assigned)

## Update

Forgot to mention that in all my components I also have this function

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token')
  return token ? next() : next('/login')
},
```

This simply check if my user is logged in based on saved token in `localStorage`

## Update 2

I've also tried to get my user type in component function like code below, but is returned `this.$store` is undefined

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    if (this.$store.getters.loggedUser.type != 'admin') {
        next({
            name: 'home'
        })
    } else {
        next()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you storing the user in vuex? You could check for ```store.getters.user.type``` in ```beforeEnter```aswell.

Comment: @dubonzi yes i am, i tried to do that in my `update part` code but it says store is undefined, not sure what else to do

Comment: @dubonzi updated my question

Comment: The component instance ```this``` is not avaliable inside ```beforeRouteEnter``` [See here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards). You should do that check inside your ```route.js``` - ```router.beforeEach```

Comment: @dubonzi would you show me how to?

Comment: Add a ```admin: true``` in the ```meta``` of your admin routes, and check the user type for all admin routes.

Comment: Yeah, Ill add a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component instance `this` is not avaliable inside `beforeRouteEnter` [See here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards).

One way to do what you want is to add another meta attribute to your admin routes and check the user type for each route that has `admin: true`.

Your router code would look something like this:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    routes: [
        // ADMIN ROUTES
        {
            path: '/dashboard',
            name: 'dashboard',
            component: Dashboard,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                admin: true
            }
        },
    ]
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        if (!store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
            next({
                name: 'login'
            })
        } 
    }
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.admin)) {
        if (store.getters.loggedUser.type !== 'admin') {
            // Do something if the user is not an admin
            // maybe redirect to a forbidden page
        }
    }
    next() 
})
```

Comment: it's strange, it redirect me to home page even my user type is admin!

Comment: Hi,can you tell me what is the `record` stands for?

Comment: @LiuYu Hi, it's based on router [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html)

Comment: There was a typo in my code. It should be ```if (store.getters.loggedUser.type !== 'admin')``` (remove the ! at the start)

Comment: @dubonzi hi man, remember this answer of yours? :) it causing me a bit of issue which i explained it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60361064/vuejs-route-redirect-on-refresh i wonder if you could check it out and give me some advice on it?