# Vuejs route redirect on refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

When i use refresh button in my browser or hit `f5` on keyboard instead of refreshing my page it redirects to home page.

## Code

`router.js`

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import store from './store';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

import NotFoundComponent from './components/NotFoundComponent.vue';

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    routes: [
        {
            path: '*',
            name: 'notFound',
            component: NotFoundComponent,
            meta: {
                breadCrumb: 'Not Found'
            }
        },
        //rest of routes...
    ]
});


router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        if (!store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
            next({
                name: 'login'
            })
        } else {
            next()
        }
    }
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.admin)) {
        if (store.getters.loggedUser.type !== 'admin') {
            next({
                name: 'home'
            })
        } else {
            next()
        }
    }
    next()
});

router.afterEach((to, from) => {
    Vue.nextTick(() => {
        document.title = to.pageTitle || 'Test App';
    });
});

export default router;
```

For instance if i am in this URL

```
https://example.com/products
```

after refresh i will redirect to

```
https://example.com
```

**Any idea?**

## Update

`route.js` full code

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import store from './store';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

//admins
import pageHome from './components/HomePage.vue';
import Dashboard from './components/admin/Dashboard.vue';
import AdminProducts from './components/admin/Products/Products.vue';
import AddProducts from './components/admin/Products/Add.vue';
import CurrencySettings from './components/admin/Settings/Currencies/Currency.vue';
import AddCurrencies from './components/admin/Settings/Currencies/Add.vue';
import editCurrencies from './components/admin/Settings/Currencies/Edit.vue';
import SlideSettings from './components/admin/Settings/Slides/Slide.vue';
import addSlides from './components/admin/Settings/Slides/Add.vue';
import editSlides from './components/admin/Settings/Slides/Edit.vue';

import categoriesSettings from './components/admin/Categories/Categories.vue';
import addCategories from './components/admin/Categories/Add.vue';
import editCategories from './components/admin/Categories/Edit.vue';

import tagsSettings from './components/admin/Tags/Tags.vue';
import addTags from './components/admin/Tags/Add.vue';
import editTags from './components/admin/Tags/Edit.vue';


import brandsSettings from './components/admin/Brands/Brands.vue';
import addBrands from './components/admin/Brands/Add.vue';
import editBrands from './components/admin/Brands/Edit.vue';


import usersSettings from './components/admin/Users/Users.vue';
import addUsers from './components/admin/Users/Add.vue';
import editUsers from './components/admin/Users/Edit.vue';


import reviewsSettings from './components/admin/Reviews/Reviews.vue';
import editReviews from './components/admin/Reviews/Edit.vue';

// users
import Register from './components/auth/Register.vue';
import Login from './components/auth/Login.vue';
import Profile from './components/auth/Profile.vue';
import SingleProduct from './components/Front/SingleProduct.vue';

import NotFoundComponent from './components/NotFoundComponent.vue';

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    routes: [
        {
            path: '*',
            name: 'notFound',
            component: NotFoundComponent,
            meta: {
                breadCrumb: 'Not Found'
            }
        },
        // ADMIN ROUTES
        {
            path: '/dashboard',
            name: 'dashboard',
            component: Dashboard,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                admin: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                name: 'dashboard',
                breadCrumb: 'Dashboard'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard/products',
            name: 'adminProducts',
            component: AdminProducts,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                admin: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                breadCrumb: 'Products'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard/products/add',
            name: 'addProducts',
            component: AddProducts,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                admin: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                breadCrumb: 'Add Product'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard/currencies',
            name: 'CurrencySettings',
            component: CurrencySettings,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                admin: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                breadCrumb: 'Currencies'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard/currencies/add',
            name: 'addCurrencies',
            component: AddCurrencies,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                admin: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                breadCrumb: 'Add Currency'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard/currencies/:id/edit',
            name: 'editCurrencies',
            component: editCurrencies,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                admin: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                breadCrumb: 'Edit Currency'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard/slides',
            name: 'SlideSettings',
            component: SlideSettings,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                admin: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                breadCrumb: 'Slides'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard/slides/add',
            name: 'addSlides',
            component: addSlides,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                admin: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                breadCrumb: 'Add Slide'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard/slides/:id/edit',
            name: 'editSlides',
            component: editSlides,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                admin: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                breadCrumb: 'Edit Slider'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard/categories',
            name: 'categoriesSettings',
            component: categoriesSettings,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                admin: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                breadCrumb: 'Categories'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard/categories/add',
            name: 'addCategories',
            component: addCategories,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                admin: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                breadCrumb: 'Add Category'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard/categories/:id/edit',
            name: 'editCategories',
            component: editCategories,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                admin: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                breadCrumb: 'Edit Category'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard/tags',
            name: 'tagsSettings',
            component: tagsSettings,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                admin: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                breadCrumb: 'Tags'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard/tags/add',
            name: 'addTags',
            component: addTags,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                admin: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                breadCrumb: 'Add Tag'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard/tags/:id/edit',
            name: 'editTags',
            component: editTags,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                admin: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                breadCrumb: 'Edit Tag'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard/brands',
            name: 'brandsSettings',
            component: brandsSettings,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                admin: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                breadCrumb: 'Brands'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard/brands/add',
            name: 'addBrands',
            component: addBrands,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                admin: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                breadCrumb: 'Add Brand'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard/brands/:id/edit',
            name: 'editBrands',
            component: editBrands,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                admin: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                breadCrumb: 'Edit Brand'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard/users',
            name: 'usersSettings',
            component: usersSettings,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                admin: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                breadCrumb: 'Users'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard/users/add',
            name: 'addUsers',
            component: addUsers,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                admin: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                breadCrumb: 'Add User'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard/users/:id/edit',
            name: 'editUsers',
            component: editUsers,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                admin: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                breadCrumb: 'Edit User'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard/reviews',
            name: 'reviewsSettings',
            component: reviewsSettings,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                admin: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                breadCrumb: 'Reviews'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard/reviews/:id/edit',
            name: 'editReviews',
            component: editReviews,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                admin: true,
                layout: 'admin',
                breadCrumb: 'Edit Review'
            }
        },
        // public routes
        {
            path: "/",
            name: 'home',
            component: pageHome,
            meta: {
                breadCrumb: 'Home Page'
            }
        },
        {
            path: "/products/:slug",
            name: 'SingleProduct',
            component: SingleProduct,
            meta: {
                breadCrumb: 'Product'
            }
        },
        // auth
        {
            path: '/profile',
            name: 'profile',
            component: Profile,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                breadCrumb: 'Profile'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/register',
            name: 'register',
            component: Register,
            meta: {
                breadCrumb: 'Register'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/login',
            name: 'login',
            component: Login,
            meta: {
                breadCrumb: 'Login'
            }
        }
    ]
});


router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        if (!store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
            next({
                name: 'login'
            })
        } else {
            next()
        }
    }
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.admin)) {
        if (store.getters.loggedUser.type !== 'admin') {
            next({
                name: 'home'
            })
        } else {
            next()
        }
    }
    next()
});

router.afterEach((to, from) => {
    Vue.nextTick(() => {
        document.title = to.pageTitle || 'Test App';
    });
});

export default router;
```

Comment: Can you show the whole routes? The order of them may have something to do with it.

Comment: @AdamOrlov you mean i share whole route.js file?

Comment: Thanks I will take a look. Have you checked vue-devtools? When you are beeing redirect are you sure you are `loggedUser === 'admin'` and your `beforeEach` if-guard doesn't fire?

Comment: i am sure about being admin about beforeEach part not exactly sure what you mean or how to check it

Comment: Looking at provided code looks like this line `store.getters.loggedUser.type !== 'admin'` is giving you a trouble. Can you delete the whole `if block` and check if this is cousing the trouble? BTW https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd

Comment: my guess is you loose your store state on refresh page. Do you use tool like [vuex-persistedstate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate) ? If not, you always fall in this condition => `store.getters.loggedUser.type !== 'admin'`

Comment: yes with commenting `store.getters.loggedUser.type !== 'admin'` my refresh issue will solve. but that was the solution that i've got for [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60311796/8490993) i'm afraid if i remove it, it cause me another issue again

Comment: and to answer your question: yes i am using vuex to keep my users login etc.

Comment: I believe it is a backend setting issue. Check if your server redirects to '/' if the page does not exists. Since Vue is a single page application your server doesn't know if the page exsits and it will redirect to '/'

Comment: @BaksaGimm it has nothing to do with backend, as i mentioned in my previous comment when i comment type !== admin part it refresh the page correctly

Comment: Does it happen on all routes?

Comment: @dubonzi yes...

Comment: @dubonzi any idea?

Comment: The only reason I can think of is the same as @Sovalina, your store is losing its state when you refresh the page, so the loggedUser check fails because the state is empty. Either that or something else not shown in your question's code

Comment: @dubonzi let assume that losing state is the issue, how should we fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solved

working code

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
      // this route requires auth, check if logged in
      // if not, redirect to login page.
      if (!store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
        next({
            name: 'login'
        })
      } else {
        next()
      }
    }
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAdmin)) {
      // this route requires auth, check if logged in
      // if not, redirect to home page.
      if (!store.getters.loggedUser.type == 'admin') {
        next({
            name: 'home'
        })
      } else {
        next()
      }
    }  
     else {
      next() // make sure to always call next()!
    }
})
```

Hope it help others.

Comment: While I found this question very useful, this solution doesn't work for me.